# IndentityServer3 sample HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden when running Host.Web

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I am running the IdentityServer3 sample from:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3
in IISExpress. When I start the Host.Web application,  I get:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I simply cloned the sample and clicked run.

My guess is that I am not starting with the correct url. Unfortunately, there is no information or "Getting Started" page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know - IdentityServer3 is no longer supported. Is there any specific reason that you are trying to use it? Why don't you head for IdentityServer4 - [Official documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/), [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) (seems that you are just starting).

If you have any concerns that IdentityServer4 is .NET Core based, and you won't be able to use it with some old legacy clients - don't worry about that, it is fully compatible with the old projects.

Besides that - IdentityServer4 has a lot of examples, better documentation and more active community.

**EDIT**

But if you are so much willing to use IdentityServer3 - [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) is the documentation for the latest release and [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/) are the samples.

But I stick to my words - if you are just starting, go for IdentityServer4.